# Python Sypherical volume

Tags: python

"Given sphere_radius and pi, compute the volume of a sphere and assign to sphere_volume. Volume of sphere = (4.0 / 3.0) π r3

Sample output for the given program: 4.18878666667"

I am to get the test to pass both when the radius of 1 is calculated and the radius of 5.5.  I can get one or the other to work but not both simultaneously.  Please assist me in correcting the code so that it will successfully pass the test to calculate sphere_volumes using the two different radius', 1 and 5.5 when I command it to print(sphere_volume)....

This is what I have and isn't working at all when I combine the two radius calculations in the code:

```
pi = 3.14159
sphere_radius = 1.0
sphere_volume = 0.0
sphere_volume=(((4.0/3.0) * 3.14159) * 1**3)
sphere_radius = 5.5
sphere_volume=(((4.0/3.0) * 3.14159) * 5.5**3)

print(sphere_volume)
```

Comment: what results do you get?  Also, the math module has math.pi for a more exact value for pi

Comment: you declare the `sphere_radius` you can use that in your `sphere_volume` equation, and you don't need to initialize `sphere_volume`...do you just need to add a `print` after the first `sphere_volume` is calculated?

Comment: how do I declare the sphere_radius?  I tried adding a print after the first sphere_volume but didn't work..It's like the answers calls for using something generic for radius so any number would do.  Is there a formula for that?

Comment: Since you're initializing values for `sphere_radius` and `pi`, you may as well use those names in your calculations rather than re-writing, for instance, `3.14159` and `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the missing print statement.  You have two volumes to report, so you have to print each as soon as calculated.

```
pi = 3.14159
sphere_radius = 1.0
sphere_volume = 0.0
sphere_volume=(((4.0/3.0) * 3.14159) * 1**3)
print(sphere_volume)

sphere_radius = 5.5
sphere_volume=(((4.0/3.0) * 3.14159) * 5.5**3)

print(sphere_volume)
```

Do note that the others have given you several good comments on improving the code:

```
pi = 3.14159

fourth_thirds = 4.0/3.0
sphere_radius = 1.0
sphere_volume = fourth_thirds * pi * sphere_radius**3
print(sphere_volume)

sphere_radius = 5.5
sphere_volume=fourth_thirds * pi * sphere_radius**3
print(sphere_volume)
```

Output:

```
4.1887902047863905
696.9099703213358
```

Comment: the program i'm using doesn't allow me to import math...it's with a zybook programming in python 3.3.  The first 3 lines of my code that I showed in the initial question are not erasable nor is the last line of the code.  All the work has to be done in between those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import math

sphere_radius = float(raw_input("Input radius: "))
sphere_volume=(((4.0/3.0) * math.pi) * sphere_radius**3)
print(sphere_volume)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kept it simple:

```
pi = 3.14159
sphere_radius = 1.0
sphere_volume = 0.0
sphere_volume = (((4.0/3.0) * pi) * sphere_radius**3)
print(sphere_volume)
```

Testing volume with radius 1.0
Your value:  4.188786666666666
  Testing volume with radius 5.5
Your value:  696.9093816666666

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the same ZyBooks Challenge activity, here is the answer:

sphere_volume = (4.0 / 3.0) * pi * sphere_radius**3